# Proxy of Chrome in Ubuntu through Terminal

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy

I will use Burp Suite and it asks for proxy (address:hostname and port is 8080) configuration change of chrome. I want to do/learn this from terminal. I saw a command

```
export https_proxy='https://proxy_ip:port'
```

After giving it in this way

```
 export http_proxy='https://127.0.0.1:8080'
```

the terminal is not showing any outcome and returning to xyzcompu:~$

Q1: How to understand whether my proxy settings **do not require/require** username password, Is there any command in the terminal to get this info.

Q2: Am I doing any mistake in giving this command

export http_proxy='https://127.0.0.1:8080'

Answer (score 0):

export sets they environment. you can do an `echo ${http_proxy}` to show what value is set (if any). The only way to know if your proxy requires username and password is by asking or trying. Do a `curl http://google.com` and see if it works, most pages redirect to HTTPS, so you need to specify the https_proxy as well. You can use `curl -v http://google.com` to get more details

Since BURP is your proxy, it's unlikely to require a username and password unless you configured one.